# problems working with 'rewrite' in apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following list of URLs to rewrite:

1 write url
  /products/**client**/

send to
  /basedir/system/index.php?client=**cliente**

2 write url
  /product/**client**/index.php

send to
  /basedir/system/index.php?client=**cliente**

3 write url
  /products/**client**/image/dir2/myimage.jpg

send to
  /basedir/system/image/**client**/dir2/myimage.jpg

4 write url
  /products/**client**/image/dir2/more_x_dir/other.img

send to
  /basedir/system/image/**client**/dir2/more_x_dir/other.img

With these rules I have more or less solved the points 1 and 2:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /basedir/system/index.php?client=base=$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /basedir/system/index.php?client=base=$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)$ /basedir/system/index.php?client=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My problem is in cases 3 and 4 when I have files with css / image's / js. and also when I have many directories, it may be that in the case of many directories have to make a rule for everyone, but I do not know how.

thank you very much

**Edit**

my solution based on the answer accepted:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)\.(gif|jpg|ico|css|js|txt|zip|xls|doc)$ /basedir/system/$2.$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /basedir/system/index.php?database=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /basedir/system/index.php?database=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z]+)/index.php$ /basedir/system/index.php?database=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)$ /basedir/system/$2?database=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me (it really could be), but I'm having a hard time figuring out what your actual questions are.

Comment: Why is the query string for the first two rules `?client=base=$1`, but the one for the third rule `client=$1`?

Comment: I can I have multiple clients to access the service and charge a different data base for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you want to do something like the following, based on your description (I'm still a little confused about the rules that you currently have). I also make the assumption that you had folders named `image`, `css`, and `js` for each client.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite images/css/js to their real files
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/(image|css|js)/(.*)$ /basedir/system/$2/$1/$3 [L]

# Rewrite everything else to the index.php script
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)(/.+)?$ /basedir/system/index.php?client=$1 [QSA,L]
```